# F# check if variable is of a subtype

Tags: f#

To check if a variable `a` has type `T`, I can use

```
if (a :? T)
```

But what if `T` is a universally-defined and has several subtypes `T1,T2,T3` in which I'm only interested in checking if `a` has type `T1`? For example:

```
type Uni = Iu of int
            | Flu of float
            | Su of string
            | Bu of bool
            | Lu of Uni List
            | Fu of (Uni -> Uni)
```

How can I check if a variable `aString` has type `Su`?

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use pattern matching with the underscore (wildcard) pattern to ignore the `float` value:

```
let isSu = function Su _ -> true | _ -> false
```

Although you can think of discriminated unions like `Uni` as class hierarchies with some base class and a number of subtypes, I do not think this is very helpful in this case. It is much better to think of them as types which can have one of several possible representations. So instead of "checking for a subtype" you are really just checking if a value is represented using the `Su` case.